How to make a package become the "deinstall" status in Ubuntu
I'm trying to check if a package is installed or not.
Here is a link for finding all packages with "deinstall" status:
dpkg --get-selections shows packages marked "deinstall"
But I can't find any packages with "deinstall" from my running Ubuntu system.
What command can be used to make a "installed" package become the "deinstall" for testing purpose?

Did you read the post it links to where it says "You can unselect the packages, which are selected for removal. ..."?

I want to simply use "dpkg -s <package_name>"  and then check the $? == 0 to check if it is installed, but I don't know if this command also works with "deinstall" packages. I never used the "--set-selections" before and I think the "--set-selections" is not the command to set the status to "deinstall" because I saw the "deinstall" once in my environment before by just "uninstall" packages with "dpkg". But I don't remember which package can produce the deinstall..

My case: It's really "uninstalled" from the system, and the status is really  in the "deinstall" and dpkg -l can show it. So it is not just a false "--set-selections" operation.

A package that has actually been uninstalled won't be in the deinstall selection. Packages in deinstall are slated to be uninstalled, they haven't been uninstalled yet.

$ dpkg -l | head -n 4
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                                  Architecture Description

Note all those | and / characters in the left edge... they are meant to point out the first two (three?) characters in the list of packages that follow these four lines (when you remove head -n 4 and actually list the packages).
If the two first characters are
ii - then the package listed on that line is actually installed
All other possible combinations are listed in those first four lines.
So
dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii' lists all actually installed packages.
dpkg -l | grep -E '^.H' should list software in Half-inst state.
I'm not sure what "deinstall" would correspond to.
Then
sudo apt install package-name - to install a package
sudo apt remove package-name - to remove (uninstall) a package
sudo apt purge package-name - to remove a package and it's  config/settings files.
